# How to remove surrounding tags in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: html, intellij-idea

In IDEA I can select a block of html and press ctrl+alt+t to surround that with a tag.  I am trying to find the option/keymapping to do the opposite... I want to select a block of html and remove the outermost surrounding tag.  Here's an example:

```
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">Hello</div>
</div>
```

If I select the #one div in the editor I should be able to have it removed, leaving only this:

```
<div id="two">Hello</div>
```

Any way to have IDEA do this for me?

Comment: When you insert surrounding tags it is a LiveTemplate functionality. It is used to 'insert frequently-used or custom code constructs', not to remove it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Code | Unwrap/Remove... <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>

(<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> on Mac)

[image]

Comment: @Peter would have been awesome to have it working in my SCSS code as well to remove surrounding parentheses...

Comment: Please file a feature request to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues#newissue with a code sample

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "XML Refactorings" > "Unwrap Tag..." in context menu. This functionality is provided by [Refactor-X](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/refactor-x.html) plugin.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, but it seems to only work for XML (not html/jsp).  Is there a way to tell the plugin to make the functionality available on jsp files?

Comment: Peter Gromov provided a better solution :)